# regular expression for language of alphabets with a substring

Tags: regex

Write a regular expression for the language of all strings over the English alphabet with “computer” as a substring. Ignore case sensitivity. In your regular expression you can use range of symbols instead of typing all the characters, such as [a - z].

I came up this expression

```
[a-z]*.’computer’.[a-z]*
```

Any comments if it is correct for my problem ?

Comment: Are you in the same class as [srk](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/11169/srk)? (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16701/regular-expression-for-a-substring)

Comment: If you want to play then check out Rubular.  I started you a session, just get rid of the word hello and mind the box to the left. http://rubular.com/r/gIEg1jKxcW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
/^[a-z]*computer[a-z]*$/i
```

Explanation:

- `/` = usual regexp delimiters
- `^` = beginning of string
- `[a-z]*` = any sequence of letters
- `computer` = match that literal string
- `$` = end of string
- `i` = case insensitive modifier

Answer (score 0):

Well, there can be a hundred answers, depends upon your definition of word and substring.

`(?i)\b(?:[a-z]+computer[a-z]*|[a-z]*computer[a-z]+)\b`

```
 (?i)
 \b
 (?:
      [a-z]+ computer [a-z]* 
   |  [a-z]* computer [a-z]+ 
 )
 \b
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need a regular expression to *detect* strings with contains word 'computer'. The RE you suggest has two problems, one is `.’` is extra and incorrect, the other is that it's not case insensitive. The below is the correct version of yours.

```
/[a-zA-Z]*computer[a-zA-Z]*/
```

To accept string with has the word computer in different *case* such as 'Computer' or 'compUter' your should yous 'ignore case **flag**'. Here it is:

```
/[\w\s]*computer[\w\s]*/i
```

as you see `i` is the flag for ignore case. Note that setting flags maybe different in different languages. Let's test this with javascript.

```js
/[\w\s]*computer[\w\s]*/i.test('Apple Computer Stores')
true
```

It also accept word that has prefixes or suffixes such is 'computerized' or 'supercomputer'. If you don't want that and need whole word only search, you should add \b like this.

```
/[\w\s]*\bcomputer\b[\w\s]*/i
```

Lets test,

```
/[\w\s]*\bcomputer\b[\w\s]*/i.test('Supercomputer')
false

/[\w\s]*\bcomputer\b[\w\s]*/i.test('Super Computer')
true
```